# An abundant of white space on bottom of webpage

Tags: css

Not sure if my syntax is wrong for other things on this page, but I am getting a lot of unneeded white space under my page.

Some troubleshooting things I have tried:
-Setting height to HTML

-Setting height to Body to 100%

-I tried to set height to Body to 100px, 200px.. just to see if it changed, which it didn't.

-I tried to set margin-bottom for Body, with no luck.

-Tried playing around with Body margin

So far no luck. I will post my code, thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Project3.css">
</head>
<body>


    <div id="setpos">
    <h1>Your Wife Is Calling For You To Come Upstairs.</p>
    <p>However, you've had a really long day and don't feel like doing that.</p></h1>
    <p> &nbsp</p>
    <p> &nbsp</p>
    <p> &nbsp</p>

    <p>Do you swallow the guilt with &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp?</p>
    <p> &nbsp</p>
    <p>Go for the &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp?</p>
    <p> &nbsp</p>
    <p>Or listen to your wife and go upstairs?</p>
        <div><a class="Mug" href="index.php"></a></div>
<div><a class="Remote" href="index.php"></a></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#setpos{
margin: 500px;
color: #5bc32d;
font-size: 30px;

}

body {
height: 100%;
position: relative;
margin: -200px -200px;
top: -110px;
}

a.Mug {
display:block;
position: relative;
background: url(../IMG/beer_hoveroff.png) no-repeat;
height: 100px;
width: 90px;
top: -350px;
left: 370px;
}

h1{
color: #500000;
font-size: 100%;
font-family: 'rokkitt', serif;

}

div{
}

a.Mug:hover {
color: #5bc32d;
background: url(../IMG/beer_hoveron.png) no-repeat;
}

a.Remote {
display:block;
position: relative;
background: url(../IMG/remote_hoveroff.png) no-repeat;
height: 110px;
width: 110px;
top: -330px;
left: 120px;
}

a.Remote:hover {
color: #5bc32d;
background: url(../IMG/remote_hoveron.png) no-repeat;
}

}
```

I do think it has something to do with my images perhaps, if so, what would be a more efficient/professional way to position things? Other than that my question is: How do I get rid of the white space under my page (http://iam.colum.edu/students/jordan.max/aim/project3.html)? And, am I doing anything wrong that I shouldn't be here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely because of this CSS right here.

```
#setpos{
    margin: 500px;
    color: #5bc32d;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

If you don't want the bottom `margin` do this instead:

```
margin: 500px 500px 0;

// or to just have the margin on the top, do this:

margin: 500px 0 0;
```

***Side note***, not sure why you're using `margin: -200px -200px;` on the `<body />` tag like that...probably not a good idea. I can only assume you put this here to offset the "white space"??

Comment: No prob. I'd probably look at removing that negative margin on the `body`. Very bad practice. Welcome to SO...if the answer fulfilled your needs, please accept. :D

Comment: Negative margins are only bad practice if you're using them incorrectly. Negative margins are not inherently bad, that's a common myth. What's so bad about them?

Comment: I would probably favor that using negative margins on the `body` tag is them being used incorrectly...